# NULL value on main report gives error

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, subreport, drilldown

I have a dril down report with sub-report.

[image: Main Report]

If I click on Never Attended - 406 it gives me error

```
The 'Section' parameter is missing a value
```

Any idea how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply a value for the 'Section' parameter.

Comment: Allea=man - I used above query in my dataset and in the report Section - =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Section.Value), "N/A", Fields!Section.Value) but still report is showing blank Section :(

Comment: Is it still giving the same error message, or only showing blank?

Comment: Yes same error message and shows blank as well under first Section (same as above screenshot)

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the parameters tab of your sub-report object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I included allow blank values in sub-report and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tab Alleman suggests, either supply a value to the parameter or code your sub report to be able to cope with its absence.

You could also use a default value where the Section is missing, such as "None" or "No Section" and code your sub report to handle that - this would be my preference because then it has meaning, rather than a blank which could indicate something wrong, but that's a personal quirk.

Comment: I am using this query but I still see a blank value for NULL section:                                                                                              SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN Section IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE Section END AS Section
FROM            Attendance_Register_Actuals_tbl
ORDER BY Section

Comment: CASE is probably overkill in this situation, you should be able to achieve the same result with and ISNULL... SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(Section, 'N/A') AS Section FROM Attendance_Register_Actuals_tbl ORDER BY Section

What does the query give you if you run it directly? You may have actual blanks or spaces in your data, rather than nulls.

Comment: I ran the query and I got a blank as you suggested. I used above query in my dataset and in the report Section - =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Section.Value), "N/A", Fields!Section.Value) but still report is showing blank Section :(